# how to fix could not load file or assembly Azure.Core'

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild-4.0

I get a runtime error : could not load file or assembly Azure.Core'

Azure.Core  is not directly added nuget package, but Azure.Identity was added.

I have two warnings :

: There was a conflict between "Azure.Identity, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8" and "Azure.Identity, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8".

There was a conflict between "Azure.Core, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8" and "Azure.Core, Version=1.20.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8".

Do I need binding redirects  ?